# Call generic WriteLine method: TestContext, Console, Trace

Tags: c#, logging, trace, system.diagnostics, console.writeline

I use `WriteLine` method for logging, tracing, diagnostics using in my code:

Unit test using **TestContext**

```
namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
    public abstract class TestContext
            public abstract void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args);
```

Other code in common componentes and libraries using **Trace**

```
System.Diagnostics
public sealed class Trace
        public static void WriteLine(string message);
```

Other code in Console applications using **Console**

```
namespace System
public static class Console
       public static void WriteLine(string value);
       public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg);
```

Usage samples:

```
    private void ShowItemsBranch(ModelBranchingMerging model)
    {
        //*** OMITTED ***
        if (anyBranch) TestContext.WriteLine(msg1);
    }

    private void ShowItemsBranch(ModelBranchingMerging model)
    {
        //*** OMITTED ***
        if (anyBranch) Console.WriteLine(msg1);
    }

    private void ShowItemsBranch(ModelBranchingMerging model)
    {
        //*** OMITTED ***
        if (anyBranch) Trace.WriteLine(msg1);
    }
```

I would like use the same source code fragment (classes, common libraries) in Unit Test project, and other projects (Addin VS, Console applications, ...).

```
    private void ShowItemsBranch(ModelBranchingMerging model)
    {
        //*** OMITTED ***
        if (anyBranch) MyInterface.WriteLine(msg1);
    }
```

Any generic solution about it?